# ASP.NET MVC4 AJAX.BeginForm AjaxOptions OnSuccess not called

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to use Jquery Model Dialog in MVC4 using Razor dialog box showing fine but  AjaxOptions.OnSuccess javascript function is not calling after i click the update button but it's redirected to  http://<>:3738/Cars/Edit/1?Length=4 i don;t know why it was happened.

Here is my Code

CarController.cs

```
public class CarsController : Controller
{
    private ExpDb db = new ExpDb();

    //
    // GET: /Cars/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Cars.ToList());
    }



    //
    // GET: /Cars/Edit/5

    public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
    {
        CarModel carmodel = db.Cars.Find(id);
        if (carmodel == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return PartialView(carmodel);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Cars/Edit/5

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult  Edit(CarModel carmodel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            db.Entry(carmodel).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            //return RedirectToAction("Index");
             return Json(JsonResponseFactory.SuccessResponse(carmodel),JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
        }
      else {
            return Json(JsonResponseFactory.ErrorResponse("Please review your form"), JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
        }
    }
```

Index.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<AjaxSamples.Models.CarModel>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<div id="commonMessage"></div>
<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ImageFileName)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ImageFileName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "editLink" }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })

        <button id="opener">Open Dialog</button>
    </td>
  </tr>



 }

</table>

 <div id="updateDialog" title="Update Car"></div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 var linkObj;
 $(function () {
    $(".editLink").button();

    $('#updateDialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 400,
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Update": function () {
                $("#update-message").html(''); //make sure there is nothing on the message before we continue                         
                $("#updateCarForm").submit();
            },
            "Cancel": function () {
                alert('sd');
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });

    $(".editLink").click(function () {
        //change the title of the dialog
        linkObj = $(this);
        var dialogDiv = $('#updateDialog');
        var viewUrl = linkObj.attr('href');
        $.get(viewUrl, function (data) {
            alert(data);
            dialogDiv.html(data);
            //validation
            var $form = $("#updateCarForm");
            // Unbind existing validation
            $form.unbind();
            $form.data("validator", null);
            // Check document for changes
            $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(document);
            // Re add validation with changes
            $form.validate($form.data("unobtrusiveValidation").options);
            //open dialog
            dialogDiv.dialog('open');
        });
        return false;
    });

});
function err(data) {
    alert(data);
}


 function updateSuccess(data) {
    alert(data);
}
```

Edit.cshtml

```
@model AjaxSamples.Models.CarModel

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Edit", "Cars", new AjaxOptions
    {
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, 
        HttpMethod = "POST",
        OnSuccess = "updateSuccess"
    }, new { @id = "updateCarForm" }))
 {
 @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<div id="update-message" class="error invisible"></div>
<fieldset>
    <legend>CarModel</legend>

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ImageFileName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ImageFileName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ImageFileName)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}

<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Comment: Have you added jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js after jquery.js to your page?

Comment: Yes i did it in the _Layout.cshtml

Comment: Have you figure out what the problem was? I'm having the same problem in my own application.

Answer (score 19):

The below Jquery File is required

jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js

Comment: This worked for me.  It is not included in the mvc5 template by default.

Comment: I spent hours trying to get Ajax.BeginForm working.  Your post solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 13):

The problem I was having is that I was declaring the success function inside $(document).ready().  I moved it outside and it worked.

i.e.:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("DialogTest", "Main", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", OnSuccess = "ajaxSuccess" }))
{
    <input type="button" id="info" value="Info" />
    <input type="button" id="confirm" value="Confirm" />
    <input type="button" id="wait" value="Wait" />
    <input type="button" id="ask" value="Ask" />
    <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}



@section Scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var ajaxSuccess = function () {
            alert('this is ajaxSuccess');
        }


        $(document).ready(function () {
            // do not declare ajaxSuccess here

            $('#mainForm').submit(function () {
                radarApp.InfoDialog("form submitted.");
                return false;
            });

// snip
```

Comment: Thanks. Life saver!

Comment: This was not obvious! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to add one more parameter in your BeginForm call:

```
Ajax.BeginForm("Edit","Cars", null, new AjaxOptions
               {
                   InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                   HttpMethod = "POST",
                   OnSuccess = "updateSuccess"
               }, new { @id = ""updateCarForm })
```

`null` is for RouteValueDictionary. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.beginform%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) are all overloads for Ajax.BeginForm method.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've replaced the code but still same issue

Comment: here with i have uploaded my complete source code for you [link]http://rvmicro.com/Ajaxsamples.rar

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Initially I had my script in the head section of the partial view...  This was causing my issues.

I moved it to the header in view that was hosting my partial view and everything worked fine.  My view is a bootstrap page hosted in a mvc application with the layout set to: "Layout = Nothing".  If your controller action is loading a view, there is definitely a issue with the jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js location...

Answer (score 1):

Try:

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Edit",  ***new {controller = "Cars"}*** , new AjaxOptions

Answer (score 0):

You can use Post method directly inside the Script tag for call the controller method like :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Cars", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "updateCarForm" }))
{
  .......Yourdata......
}
```

and then in the Jquery

```
function PostForm(url) {
    $("#updateCarForm").valid();
    if ($("#updateCarForm").valid()) {
    $.post(url, $("#updateCarForm").serialize(), function (data) { updateSuccess(data); });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. but what is the actual issue in the current code.

Comment: Why are you changing the OP's `Ajax.BeginForm()` to `Html.BeginForm()`?

Comment: In my suggestion i am not using Ajax i suggest him the other solution of the Post method for that i place `Html.BeginForm()` at there.

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error in @Alex's code, this should be working:

```
Ajax.BeginForm("Edit","Cars", null, new AjaxOptions
           {
               InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
               HttpMethod = "Post",
               OnSuccess = "updateSuccess"
           }, new { id = "updateCarForm" })
{ /* Razor code */ }
```

Specifically you should be looking at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470626%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) overload of `Ajax.BeginForm()`.

Comment: still not working here with i have uploaded my complete source code to you [link]http://rvmicro.com/Ajaxsamples.rar

Comment: @ravikumar what isn't working? Is there exception being thrown? Script errors? Use the debugging tools from Google Chrome or Fiddler to give more details.

Comment: there is no exception being thrown. it's simply redirect to http://localhost:3738/Cars/Edit/1?Length=4 and given json data.

Comment: Did you include the `null`? If you have it shouldn't be redirecting with the query string

Comment: yes i did it's redirected without query string but "updateSuccess" javascript not called.

Comment: I've identified the issue. it's the problem with Jquery version previously i've used jquery1.9.1.js now i've changed to jquery-1.7.1.js. it's working fine. but i don't understand why it's causing the higher version of jquery.